# C# program that takes an integer as input and then displays a rectangle using that integer

Tags: c#

I am a new learner of C# programming language. I came to know about StackOverflow that I can get the answers to my questions by experienced programmers.
I have made this program that takes an integer as input and makes a rectangle of a given number of rows and columns using that integer. And it's working! but I want a simpler way of doing that.

And sorry in advance if it is hard to read

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rectangle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Your Number: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter no. of rows: ");
            int rows = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter no. of colums: ");
            int cols = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                if(i == 0 || i == (rows - 1)) //In the first and last row, it will print all the column elements
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(n);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else //In the mid section, only first and last column elements will be printed
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < cols; z++)
                    {
                        if (z == 0 || z == (cols - 1)) //first and last column elements printed
                        {
                            Console.Write(n);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //in the mid-column, there should be no. of spaces equal to the no. of digits to form a perfect rectangle
                            for (int l = 0; l < Convert.ToString(n).Length; l++)
                            {
                                Console.Write(" ");
                            }
                        }                     
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }         
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did a little fun exercise to make it short

Comment: And not very readable but oh well, what can ya do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Heres your simplified version, enjoy

```
using System;
namespace Rectangle{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){

            Console.Write("Enter Your Number: ");
            string n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())+"",s=new String(' ',n.Length);
            Console.Write("Enter no. of rows: ");
            int r = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter no. of colums: ");
            int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
                    Console.Write(j==0||j==c-1||i==0||i==r-1?n:s);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Or a single loop one, if you like golf

```
using System;
namespace Rectangle{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){

            Console.Write("Enter Your Number: ");
            string n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())+"",s=new String(' ',n.Length);
            Console.Write("Enter no. of rows: ");
            int i=0,c,r=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter no. of colums: ");
            c=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for(;i<r*c;i++)Console.Write(i%r==0||i%r==r-1||i/r==0||i/r==c-1?n+(i%r==r-1?"\n":""):s);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Or this neat thing :)

```
namespace System{using i=Console;class Program{static void Main(){i.Write("number: ");
string                                                                          n=int.
Parse(i.                                                                        ReadLine
())+"",s                                                                        =new String
(' ',n.                                                                         Length);i.
Write(                                                                          "rows: ");
int j=0,                                                                        c,r=int.
Parse(i.                                                                        ReadLine
());i.                                                                          Write(
"columns: "                                                                     );c=int.
Parse(i.                                                                        ReadLine
());for                                                                         (;j<r*c;
j++)i.Write(j%r==0||j%r==r-1||j/r==0||j/r==c-1?n+(j%r==r-1?"\n":""):s);i.ReadLine();}}}
```